# Is there calculation time limit in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Array Formula in Google Sheet to calculate some values.

Each row has around 200 fields (from Google form).

Using the array formula, I've multiplied each column to a cell in another sheet (200 fields there).

The response has the no of units 1, 2, 3, ... and another sheet has price 5, 10, 100.

So, each unit is being calculated by its price to get a total value.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!T2:T),0,'Form Responses 1'!T2:T * Data!T2))
```

Ok, then I've to find the total sum of all these results, for that, I'm using MMULT.

```
=MMULT(T2:EV100,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(T2:EV100)^0)))
```

Now, the actual problem is that the ArrayFormula is only showing the result (the value 0) to 104 rows only.

Is there a limitation on the amount of calculation? Or the rows will increase over time?

I've tried ArrayFormula in an isolated sheet, and it goes to the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Poor me.

I just noticed that the sheet attached with Google form had only 103 rows, that is why the arrayFormula was only showing results till 103 rows.

I added 1000 more rows and it expanded. But it is slower than before, I guess the calculations are being performed in my browser.